# Bake missing in Blender 2.83

Tags: fluid-simulation

I'm new to blender, and I'm trying some basic water sims.

I can't see Bake in the UI anywhere, and I've been looking for over an hour...

[image]
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to bake your simulation you need the Physics properties > Cache > Type to be set to either modular which allows you to pause the bake in between and resume it or final which does not allow these options.

If its set to Replay simulation will be baked using the timeline itself and no "Bake" button will be present. (You will need to start from frame 0 to reset the simulation)

Comment: Many thanks, I'm just starting out. It's magnificent but the learning curve is steep.